# Django a simple query makes me crazy ''int' object is not iterable'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have two Models:

```
class MasterData(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Companyname = models.CharField('Companyname', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    UserID = models.IntegerField('UserID')

class Prefixes(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    UserID = models.ForeignKey('MasterData', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    InvoiceNoPrefix = models.CharField('InvoiceNoPrefix', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
```

No I want in my view a make a simple objects.get_or_create if you visit the site the first time and no records exist should it create one.

```
@login_required(login_url='/backend/')
def edit_prefixes(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    userfrommasterdata = MasterData.objects.filter(UserID__in=user_id)
    prefixes_data = Prefixes.objects.get_or_create(UserID=userfrommasterdata)
```

And all what I get is a: 'int' object is not iterable

What do I miss? On my MasterData view it's working perfectlit:

```
@login_required(login_url='/backend/')
def edit_masterdata(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    # stamdata_data = get_object_or_404(Stamdata, pk=user_id)

    stamdata_data, _ = MasterData.objects.get_or_create(UserID__iexact=user_id, UserID=user_id)
```

Comment: you need to wrap the user id with square brackets: `userfrommasterdata = MasterData.objects.filter(UserID__in=[user_id])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter() will always give you a QuerySet, even if only a single object matches the query - in this case, it will be a QuerySet containing a single element.

If you know there is only one object that matches your query, you can use the get() method which returns the object directly:

More Information from [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get)

try this:
**userfrommasterdata = MasterData.objects.filter(UserID=user_id).first()**

```
@login_required(login_url='/backend/')
def edit_prefixes(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    userfrommasterdata = MasterData.objects.filter(UserID=user_id).first()
    prefixes_data, _ = Prefixes.objects.get_or_create(UserID=userfrommasterdata)
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but what does the .first() mean? Will I always get the right UserID also if I delete a MasterData set and user.id from django differ from masterdata id?

Comment: thank you very much, have a nice coding :)